# Sort columns based on data in tuples mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Say, I have a table

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
1   2   4   3   6   5
4   2   3   1   6   5
4   5   3   6   1   2
```

How can one get an output based on rearranging based on its data. For example,

```
ABDCFE
DBCAFE
EFCABD
```

is it possible?

EDIT:

The question seems to be asking:  How can I get the list of column names in order by value?

Comment: Is this a riddle or are you still adding some explanation?

Comment: @juergend: Please explain what more info I should include.

Comment: I don't see what your output has to do with the input.  Please revise the question so it is clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I meant that if I chose a tuple, then based on its data, can I sort its columns. I believe my expectations are wrong. Like substituting column name at last. I am not from db background, so I was attempting things.

Comment: Now that I have figured out the question, it is not as awfully written as I thought.

Comment: If you are , then the output you state in your question is inconsistent with "just sorting the columns".  The values in the columns are not the column names ('A' through 'F') they are integers between 1 and 5.  Do you simply want each row of the output to specify the order of the values in columns A through F ?

Comment: @CharlesBretana: I want kind of replacement of column names for values at last.  Gordon's answer is helpful. It does exactly this.

Comment: @Rorschach, no worries. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.  You want to sort the values in each row and show the names of the columns in order.

Let me assume that you have a row id, so you can identify each row.  Then:

```
select id, group_concat(which order by val) as ordered_column_names
from ((select id, a as val, 'A' as which from t) union all
      (select id, b, 'B' as which from t) union all
      (select id, c, 'C' as which from t) union all
      (select id, d, 'D' as which from t) union all
      (select id, e, 'E' as which from t) union all
      (select id, f, 'F' as which from t)
     ) t
group by id
order by id;
```

Comment: Thanks and this is exactly what I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are asking for output where each row in the output is just a specification of the order of the data values in the columns.
Then, if the values are always integers between 1 and 5, you can do it by outputting a character value of 'A' where the data value is 1, a 'B' where the data value is 2, etc. This SQL will do that.

```
Select Char(A+64)A, Char(B+64) B, 
  Char(C+64) C, Char(D+64) D, 
  Char(E+64) E, Char(F+64) F
From table
```

if the want the column sort order in one output column, you could also do this:

```
Select Char(A+64) + Char(B+64) + 
  Char(C+64) + Char(D+64) +
  Char(E+64) + Char(F+64) SortOrder
From table
```

Comment: I am afraid I am not getting what I need using this.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is fundamentally not the tool to do the operation you describe, because it violates the concept of a [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)). I don't mean the common use of "relation" meaning a relation*ship*, I mean the mathematical definition of relation.

- There is no order of columns in a relation. The columns are a set, which is by definition unordered. Columns are identified by their name, not their position left-to-right.
- All the entries in rows under each respective named column must be part of the same data domain. If you mix them around on a row-by-row basis, you're violating this.

I guess all your columns A through F are actually using values in the same data domain, or else reordering them wouldn't make any sense. If this is true, then you're violating [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) by defining a table with repeating groups of columns. You should instead have all six columns be in one column of a second table. Then it becomes very easy to sort them by value.

Basically, what you're trying to do is better solved by formatting the data results in some application code.

Comment: I agree, I should look into normalization. Your explanation is very nice actually.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it ,get coulmn name by column ordinal order and print it.
For each value in coulmn iterate this and get the column name for the ordinal specified in cloumn data. Here ordinal position is value in each coulmn data. Iterate for each row and each column and your problem is solved.

```
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'my_table_name' and ordinal_position = 2;
```

Comment: As I learn more, in future I will try this suggestion as well. Thanks for hint.